# Copying from ananconda prompt gives bad format when pasting

Tags: anaconda, windows-10

I am trying to copy paste the output of anaconda prompt.

Right now I copy by selecting what I want, and coing CTRL+SHIFT+C.

This copies the content but then when I paste it into a editor (Notepad++ or Notepad) the contents are pasted but with a lot of spaces and I have to arrange all manually to be readable

Does anyone know a way to copy paste without this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to copy? This seems like it might be off-topic, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this (by chance).
To copy paste from ananconda prompt, first select the part you want to copy. Then *don't do Ctrl whatever C*. Instead having the part selected, right-click on the title bar and look for the Copy part in the Menu that appears. (in my case it was Edit->Copy)

Once I did that, I can simple to Ctrl-v in Notepadd++ and the part gets pasted correctly

Answer (score -1):

Try Ctrl + Shift + V ( this should paste as plain text)

Comment: @KansaiRobot What editor are you using, perhaps try a drag and drop

Comment: Notepad++ and even the simple Notepad

Comment: Tried drag'n'drop?